# NoSQL Data Modeling about "one to many" relationships

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

Good evening,

I'm trying to develop a small data model with MongoDB as backend. It's my first time developing with NoSQL databases and data models.

The big idea is this: there are a bunch of SERVICES that can be done and each SERVICE is doable in different places. As an example let's think of a website that shows where to eat (the Service), there are multiple places where you can do that, so there's 1 Service (EAT) for many places (PLACES).

I don't know how to model this, any ideas?

```
SERVICE {
_id: ObjectId,
Name: String,
Code: String
} // Data model for the Service Collection?

PLACES {
_id: ObjectId,
NameOfPlace: String,
Service1: String,
Service2: String,
...
Servicen: String
} /* This way, by using the flexibility of MongoDB, 
updating the document each time with some new (key, value).
Doesnt seem elegant nor efficient.*/

PLACES {
_id: ObjectId,
NameOfPlace: String,
Services: {
           NameOfService1: refID SERVICE COLLECTION,
           NameOfService2: refID SERVICE COLLECTION..
          }
} // Maybe this way is better? No idea how to do those tho'
```

Any better solutions that you can explain to me? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider modeling them using references. Basically, a Place has a collection of Serivce's Ids

```
SERVICE {
_id: ObjectId,
Name: String,
Code: String
}

PLACES {
_id: ObjectId,
NameOfPlace: String,
Services: [Service1_id, Service2_id, ...]

}
```

You may read the following links for implementation details

[MongoDB - Data Modeling introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

[MongoDB - Model One-to-many relationship with reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came up with the same solution after a few headaches but I believe it could be useful to vote this one as the right answer, making it possible for other people to find the answer! Thanks again!

Comment: What about if there are millions of services, would that design still be good?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should be stored within one collection as a nested sub-document OR an array of places. NoSql should be used for such requirements with nested data objects/arrays rather than traditional RDBMS relationships.